# SQL Trailing Date Count

Tags: sql, date, time

I have a need to do a calculation based on trailing dates when a customer placed an order.
SQL Code to get the following table:

```
select Date,Cust, ProdID, OrderLog 
from AUDIT AS A 
where Date >= '2021-02-07' 
  and Cust = '477' 
  and Prod ID = 'X' 
order by A.Date desc
```

| Date | Cust | ProdID | OrderLog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/18/2021 | 477 | X | Null |
| 2/17/2021 | 477 | X | 1 |
| 2/16/2021 | 477 | X | 1 |
| 2/15/2021 | 477 | X | 1 |
| 2/14/2021 | 477 | X | Null |
| 2/13/2021 | 477 | X | Null |

What I want to do is count the days from 1st OrderLog Date, 2/15/2021, to last OrderLog Date 2/17/2021. For an outcome of 3.

I tried to do this in a window function using lag/over/partition with no luck. I also tried searching for the solution with no luck.

There is a need to do this in one query containing multiple Cust,PRODID and Dates. The count need to be at Cust and ProdID level.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select Cust, ProdID,
       max(date) - max(case when OrderLog = 1 then date end) as diff
from AUDIT AS A
where Date >= '2021-02-07' and
      Cust = '477' and Prod ID = 'X'
group by cust, prodid;
```

Note that date/time functions vary among databases, so your database might use something other than `-` to subtract two dates.

Comment: That is almost what I want. I modified the sample you provided to get my desired output. However, how do I add in date to the line of when it was last recorded?                                                                                                                     
SQL Code:    select Cust, prodid,  
  
DateDiff(day,
max(case when WillCall =1 then date end), min(case when WillCall = 1 then date end)) AS Diff
from AUDIT
where date >= '2021-02-07' and
Cust = '477' and  prodid = 'X'
group by Cust, prodid;